# Send form action to a private directory

Tags: php

I want to send my form request to a folder which is not public accessible.
My directory structure is like this-

- /home/www/public_html/

  - inc

    - action.php
  - public_html  (*This is the public directory*)

    - form.php (*I want to process this form action with action.php*)

I tried with this code-

```
<form action="../inc/action.php" method="POST">
```

But, it shows **404! Not Found** error while I submit the form. It says the path - *mysite.com/inc/action.php* is not found.

Is there any way in php to process form request in private directories?

Comment: The short answer is: no. The medium answer is: not this way. The complete answer is: yes; either put `action.php` in `public_html` or write an `action.php` in `public_html` that `include "../inc/action.php";`. That's all.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently doing exactly the same thing. I just created another folder "inc" which includes that file. But think, in this way, it is same thing keeping the action.php file in the private folder or public_html .
Am I right?

Comment: The whole point of being private is actively preventing the scenario you want to accomplish. It's like asking how to log in with a disabled user.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the "Front controller" design pattern, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller

Basically it means you let a file in you public folder (ex. index.php, app.php,...) handle every web request. The code in that file will then determine which files needed to be executed/loaded in your private folder.